# how to store form data in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I run the following code but it's displaying array values not storing data into mysqldb.

```
<?php

       if(! empty( $_POST)){
        print_r($_POST);exit;
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','mydb');
        if($mysqli->connect_error){
        die('connect error:'. $mysqli->connect_errno .':' . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        }

?>
```

register.php:

```
    <?php
     require('db.php');
     $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $name1 = $_POST['skill'];
     $name2= $_POST['exp'];
     $name3 = $_POST['sele'];
     $sql = "INSERT INTO register VALUES('".$name."','".$name1."','".$name2."','".$name3."')";
    $insert = $mysqli->query($conn,$sql);
    echo $insert;
     ?>
```

Getting array result in browser

Comment: Please have a look at PDO and how to bind parameters. Your use of raw _POST data with sql is a security issue. Plus, pdo have much more advantages.

Comment: @cyrbil - you can do prepared statements (with bound parameters) with the `mysqli` library as well you know ... I'm not saying the OP shouldn't use PDO but bound parameters isn't, in itself, total justification for doing so.

Comment: @CD001: you are right ! So long time I didn't use mysqli ^^", still pdo is my bread and butter

Answer (score 1):

The connection object is already defined - `$mysqli`. Why `$conn` again? Just do -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO register VALUES('".$name."','".$name1."','".$name2."','".$name3."')";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

`$conn` will be required if you were using the `procedural` approach.

[mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:  `$insert = $mysqli->query($conn,$sql);`

With:

```
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's start by the beginning.

- Use PDO (optional). You look like a newbie, so start with good bases.
- Check if your _POST variables exist (and eventually check for type (not array))
- Use bindparam to automatically insert data (without risk of sql injections)

```
$fields = ["name", "skill", "exp", "sele"];
$params = [];
foreach($fields as $field) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$field])) {
        exit("Field required: $field");
    }
    $params[":$field"] = $_POST[$field];
}

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 'username', 'password');
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
    INSERT INTO register VALUES(:name, :skill, :exp, :sele);
');
$sth->execute($params);
```

If you still wanna stick with mysqli ...

```
$fields = ["name", "skill", "exp", "sele"];
$params = [];
foreach($fields as $field) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$field])) {
        exit("Field required: $field");
    }
    $params[":$field"] = $_POST[$field];
}

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');
$query = $mysqli->prepare('
    INSERT INTO register VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
');
call_user_func_array(array($query, "bind_param"), $params);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: If he want's to use mysqli procedural or OOP instead of PDO I think that's fine as long as he isn't using `mysql_*` which he doesn't

Comment: It's not great practice to call out the OP for having so many problems if you're then going to post non-functional code that is, in itself, also full of problems.

Comment: Edit made including mysqli version to satisfy OP desiderata

Comment: Hint: *Call to undefined method PDO::execute()*